# What am I doing wrong with trying to get my Disqus plugin to work?

Tags: html, disqus

I'm slowly building a website and it's just saved on my desktop right now. I'm trying to place `Disqus` on one of my pages and I pasted the code in the HTML document and I'm not getting anything on my page. I was able to successfully get my twitter widget to work on a different page just by pasting the code that was given to me and the same type of instruction was given from `Disqus` which was to paste the universal code to my site but nothing is showing up.

Do I have to do something with a CSS file to get it showing? I was searching through the settings in `Disqus` and one of the settings allows me to set the website URL but my website is not live and is just located in a folder in my desktop containing my html and CSS files.

I created a test HTML document in the folder containing all my HTML documents but I only get the sentence contained in the paragraph tag.

```
   <! DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <title>Test-Disqus</title>
        </head>

        <body>

        <p> Testing Disqus.</p.>

        <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
            var disqus_shortname = 'myusername';  /***changed for this question*///

            /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
            (function() {
                var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
            })();
        </script>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>


        </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues with your HTML, however it's not the root cause of your issue.

1) It's <!DOCTYPE html> not <! DOCTYPE html>

2) Your closing paragraph tag has a ".", it should be </p> and not </p.>

You said, "I'm slowly building a website and it's just saved on my desktop right now."  If you're opening this test file directly from your desktop using your web browsers, the disqus module will not load.  Disqus restricts the comment module to only load on trusted domains set by you.  You can check the trusted domain by logging into disqus -> admin -> settings -> advanced.

You can add additional trusted domains if you need.  However if your trusted domain is "xyz.com" and you load your test page from your desktop, the trusted domain will not match.

You need to run a webserver to get it working, I recommend MAMP for local development.  MAMP will most likely start up on port 8888 or 8080. This will allow you to access your test file by going to http://localhost:8080/test.html.  After that you can try adding localhost as a trusted domain, or create an entry in your host file.